# Number of ideals with GAP

Tags: combinatorics, ring-theory, representation-theory, gap, constraint-programming

Let $A=K\langle x,y\rangle$ be the polynomial in non-commuting variables $x,y$ over a finite field $K$ with $q$ elements and $J=\langle x,y\rangle$ the ideal generated by $x$ and $y$.

I want to find all ideals I having the property that $J^4 \subseteq I \subset J^2$.

It is a finite problem and the most stupid idea goes as follows:

We can write $I=J^4+X$ , where $X$ is the ideal generated by a subset of the $K$-vector space $V$ spanned by the elements $x^2, xy, yx ,y^2, xyx, xy^2, x^3, x^2y, yx^2, yxy, y^2x, y^3$.

Now $V$ has $q^{12}$ elements and $X$ can be any subset.

So I have $2^{q^{12}}$ possibilities, which are $2^{4096}$ when the field has $2$ elements :(( .

> Is there any good idea to improve finding all possible $X$ using GAP?

For example when $X$ contains $x^2$ , then it is not necessary that there is also the relation $x^2y$ or $x^3$ since they are in the ideal automatically then.

> Is it realistic that GAP can produce all ideals and how many are there?

It would be also interesting to see how many ideals there are up to isomorphism, where two ideals $I_1$ and $I_2$ are isomorphic when $A/I_1$ and $A/I_2$ are isomorphic as $K$-algebras.

For simplicity we can assume first that $K$ is the field with two or three elements.

Comment: What do you mean? all my A/I will be finite dimensional since i factor out something larger than J^4. In your example (xy^3) is not a ideal having the right conditions, since it does not contain J^4.

Comment: Yes the problem can be formulated to count the ideals of $F_q <x,y>/J^4$ contained in $J^2/J^4$, where the polynomial ring here is the noncommutative one. If you have a solution for the commutative one, that might be also interesting.

Comment: The problem is to count the ideals of $\mathbb{F}_q[x,y]/J^4$. It is $\mathbb{F}_q[M_1,\ldots,M_k]$ where $M_k$ are the $4 \times 4$ matrices with minimal polynomial $M^4 = 0$

Comment: Instead of forming collections of elements, first form the different principal ideals generated by individual elements and then form combinations of principal ideals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QPA can in principle find all the different ideals in question through the command

```
AllSubmodulesOfModule
```

(in the latest version on GitHub, https://github.com/gap-packages/qpa).

Constructing the algebra $A = K\langle x, y\rangle/J^3$ and considering the ideal $J^2/J^3$ as a module $M$ over the enveloping algebra of $A$, then finding all ideals $I$ with the property that $J^3\subseteq I \subseteq I^2$ is the same as finding all submodules of $M$. Here is how you can do it in QPA:

```
Q := Quiver(1,[[1,1,"a"],[1,1,"b"]]);;
KQ:= PathAlgebra(GF(2), Q);;
AssignGeneratorVariables(KQ);;
rels := AddNthPowerToRelations( KQ, [], 3 );;
A:= KQ/rels;;
M := AlgebraAsModuleOverEnvelopingAlgebra(A);;
radM := RadicalOfModule(M);;
rad2M := RadicalOfModule(radM);;
test := AllSubmodulesOfModule( rad2M );;
Length(Flat(test));
27;
```

The number of ideals are 27 in this case.  For the case $J^4\subseteq I \subseteq J^2$, the number of ideals are quite a bit larger.  It took long time to complete, but I lost the result (maybe corresponding number was 573).

I hope that this is a helpful comment.

Best regards, The QPA-team.